# INSERT INTO in MS Access 2010 SOMETIMES GETS ERROR: 3073 Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I get the `ERROR: 3073   Operation must use an updateable query` **SOMETIMES**, while performing an `INSERT` statment.

I have no problem on my windows 7 PC, but the person I am writing this for sometimes gets the error.  She also has MS Access 2010 on Windows 7.

As I said I have never got it on my PC, and she only gets it sometimes.  The code will insert a number of rows and then through the error, and other times not through the erro at all.

The error occurs if I have the code and data in one .mdb file or seperate files.
Here a snippet of code:

```
OrderHdrInsertStmnt = " INSERT INTO ORDER_HDR " _  
& "(ORDER_ID, SOURCE_CODE, ORDER_DATE, SHIP_FNAME, SHIP_LNAME, SHIP_EMAIL, SHIP_COMP, SHIP_PHONE, SHIP_ADDR, SHIP_CITY, SHIP_STATE, SHIP_ZIP, SHIP_CNTRY, " _  
& " BILL_FNAME, BILL_LNAME, BILL_EMAIL, BILL_COMP, BILL_PHONE, BILL_ADDR, BILL_CITY, BILL_STATE, BILL_ZIP, BILL_CNTRY, " _  
& " TAX, SHIPPING, TOTAL, MOD_DATE, INSERT_DATE) " _  
& " VALUES (" _  
& "'" & OrderId & "','" & SourceCode & "','" & Orderdate & "','" & ShipFName & "','" & ShipLName & "','" & ShipEmail & "','" & ShipComp & "','" & ShipPhone & "','" & ShipAddr & "','" & ShipCity & "','" & ShipState & "','" & ShipZip & "','" & ShipCntry _  
& "','" & BillFName & "','" & BillLName & "','" & BillEmail & "','" & BillComp & "','" & BillPhone & "','" & BillAddr & "','" & BillCity & "','" & BillState & "','" & BillZip & "','" & BillCntry _  
& "','" & OrderTax & "','" & OrderShipping & "','" & OrderTotal & "','" & ImportDate & "','" & ImportDate & "');"
```

then I use

```
dbsCurrent.Execute OrderHdrInsertStmnt, dbFailOnError
```

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: Are all of those fields VarChar/Strings?

Comment: I have a mixture.  there are String, Double, Date, and Lon variable types.

Comment: Are values (that you are trying to insert) same? for e.g. the values of OrderId, OrderDate

Comment: I trapped the error, paused 1/2 a second and resume(d) so to attempt the INSERT again. 

I keep track of the total attempts and for each insert. If an individual insert reaches 5 attempts I still fail the process otherswise I report on the total attempts in the log file. 

Seems like the parent table in the database mdb file is still locked and the next insert into a child table fails because of this. That's ACCESS for ya!

Again, this error did not occur consistantly, and never on my PC.  It occured on a different PC that has more memory, and faster CPU.  Very strange!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting usually occurs when you run an update statement against a query so it is not clear which records should be updated.  You are obviously not doing that.

Is it possible then that some of the data you are concatenating into the insert statement is sometimes of wrong value, for instance string in a number or NULL or the like.  That would be the most likely explanation.  The most likely cause of error is some kind of non-standard input which gets concatenated into the statement.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The thing that is confusing is that I do not get this error on my PC, but another perosn does.  We have the same access files, and everything (seriously).  The only difference is the computer.  This is part of an import process, and sometimes everything imports fine and the next time it doesn't.  I just wish I could recreate the issue on my PC.

Comment: What format is the import source, and how are you opening it?

Comment: I trapped the error, paused 1/2 a second and resume(d) so to attempt the INSERT again. I keep track of the total attempts and for each insert. If an individual insert reaches 5 attempts I still fail the process otherswise I report on the total attempts in the log file. Seems like the parent table in the database mdb file is still _locked_ and the next insert into a child table fails because of this. That's ACCESS for ya!

Comment: What about answering the question about what the import source is and how you're opening it? What you've described is not a solution, but nobody can help if you don't provide more information.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton   The import file is a tab delimited text file. I do a Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") and then Set OrderFile = fso.OpenTextFile(OrderFileNameAndLocation, ForReading).  I then loop through the file and     OrderRecordIn = OrderFile.ReadLine.  I honestly do not see why this has anything to do with the error.  the erro is not consistent.  I can process the same file again and again, and each time it will fail on a different line.  It only happens on 1 PC and not the other 2.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, you didn't say how you were doing the import. In certain circumstances, if the file extension is not one Access acknowledges for the import type, it can cause problems. Opening the file and looping through it and importing record-by-record may not be the most efficient method. It might be possible to use a data interface that can open the file and import it in a batch, but it depends on a number of factors you've not given explicit details for.

Answer (score 0):

Are the tables shared and are you both updating/inserting at the same time?

I'm running tests of multiuser updates on the same records.
The table is : one id and one text field,
the query is: update text = randomString WHERE id = 800 (id 800 exists...)
Execute method: CurrentDb.Execute(qry)

10 times over 200 on each computer I had the error 3073. I thus suppose this means "table locked by someone else"

For info, on an other test (same table) but in insert mode using a recordset addNew and Update I had the error 3343 (Database format not recognized)

Explicit messages :P

Comment: No they are not.  I have temporarily fixed it by adding a "retry".  If I get the error I wait 1 second and then do it again.  I have never had to wait more than once, but I have written it so that if it tries more than 5 times for any insert then it exists the process.  Not the cleanest way, but it has bandaided the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a standalone Visual Basic program using MS Access DB for a friend more than 2 years ago.  Recently , he complained encountering "Operation must use an updateable query" error when adding the second record in a session.  That is: each time he use the program, only the 1st record is added/updated.

After searching the web, various forum, I cannot find a likely answer.

Eventually, the solution/get-around of my case: seems that my friend's newly installed backup software (Memeo Backup) running in the background is somehow causing the problem.  Disable the backup program, the program can work again.

So, try disable background programs and see if any of them is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on an insert. I was inserting into a linked table using a VALUES clause, which was running from VBA. When I moved the insert destination table into the local mdb, it solved the problem. Then I was able to insert all the rows from the local table into the linked table.